# What is the Difference of -c and -wi paramters of LibSVM

Tags: libsvm

I have an unbalanced data and I want to use LibSVM at matlab. LibSVM has two different parameters for cost: -c and -wi. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-c** option is to set the hyper-parameter value. Since, you have unbalanced data, it tries to minimize error for class with large number of examples compared to class with less number of examples.
Now, one-way is to somehow suggest to the algorithm that error for class with smaller number of examples should be given more weightage compared to the other class. You do so by using the **-w** option.
Say: You have two classes +1 and -1. +1 examples are less in number compared -1 class.So, you want to give more weightage to +1 class. Now, you can set the parameters as,
`-w+1 10 -c C`
would indicate that error for positive class should be given roughly 10 times more weightage than negative class in Binary Classification.
The values to be used with **-c** and **-w** are selected using cross-validation technique.